# Sed operation on streaming data

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Need to perform `sed` operation on streaming data

```
tail -f sourcefile | sed -n 's/text1/text2/p' >~/destinationfile
```

I tried the above command but could not get it to work.

Comment: Could you specify just how the command didn't work? Thanks.

Comment: Are you SURE it's not working? You are mostl likely just being caught out by buffering.

Comment: Note that you only print the lines that contain `text1`; any other line is effectively deleted (not printed).  If you really want to see everything, drop the `-n` and the `p` in `s///p`.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. your suggestion worked, but there is difference in the number of lines in source-file and destination-file in the end.      1211841 : source file  1211811: destination_file

Answer (score 5):

Both programs are linked against libc and the libc performs internal buffering on input/output operations. Buffering will be line-based when stdout(!) is a terminal but block-based when stdout is a pipe. The block-based buffering uses larger buffers and the consuming application has to wait until the buffer is filled, or the end of the stream is reached or the program calls `flush()` on the file descriptor. However neither `tail` nor `sed` calling `flush()` (with default command line options).

In your case you can see block based buffering of tail's stdin in effect. This happens because stdout is going into a pipe to tail.

**Solution**: You can issue the `stdbuf` command to disable the input buffering of tail:

*if you only want to see sed's output in terminal:*

```
stdbuf -i0 tail -f /var/log/syslog | sed -n 's/CRON/cron/p'
```

*if you are piping to a file sed's output buffer now needs to be disabled as well!*

```
touch output.txt
tail -f output.txt & # tail output in background in order to see
                     # file changes immediately

stdbuf -i0 tail -f /var/log/syslog | stdbuf -o0 sed -n 's/CRON/cron/p' > output.txt
```

Comment: And give the `sed` the option `-u` to make this _also_ unbuffered; probably you want to  see the results pretty fast in the destination file.  Or use `stdbuf` again for the `sed` in case your `sed` doesn't have a `-u`.

Comment: I'm wondering … why are you setting the stdin-buffer of `tail` to 0?  Isn't also the stdout buffered?

Comment: This is a remaining question. It appeared in tests that it is neither required to disable tail's output buffering nor sed's stdin buffering. I guess this behaviour is "hardcoded" in the source code of that programs. But I'm not sure. Will check this, but not today. We are both in the same timezone I guess ;)

Comment: the suggestion from Jonathan worked, where i removed '-n' in 'sed -n' and 'p' in 'sed -n 's/text1/text2/p'. But there was difference in the final number of lines in the source file and destination file. Thanks for the explenation. was really helpful

Comment: @kris433 I wouldn't had expected that this could do trick. Maybe because I'm tested not *exactly* the same command as you. I should have. You are welcome :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Hi, i forgot to mention i'm running these commands on Unix. when i tried tue comand you suggested, it says stdbuf:not found. do we have another alternative in unix. And also why do you think i'm getting the difference in number of lines. Thanks again

Comment: @kris433 Sorry for the late response. I've googled for `stdbuf BSD` and found this http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stdbuf .. Hope this helps